# Targeting IE Using Conditional Comments and Just One Stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer

**Updated: [See third technique at the bottom of this question regarding Paul Irish's technique!]**

I'm wondering what the web devs out there think about these two methods? Which is best? Considerations for both?

**Method 1:**

Single CSS File for all styles, with conditional comments in wrapper divs to apply specific IDs to HTML.

CSS

```
  /*** For IE 7 and up ***/

#ie7andup #anyelement {
    border-color : blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<div id="ie7andup">
<![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <div id="ie6only">
    <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 5.5000]>
        <div id="ie5-5only">
        <![endif]-->

            <!--[if lt IE 5.5000]>
            <div id="ie5-01only">
            <![endif]-->

<div id="anyelement">a box with some content</div>

[... more page content ...]


    <!--[if IE]>
    </div>
    <![endif]-->
```

(via http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html)

**Method 2:**

Separate IE stylesheets, with conditional comments including those CSS files.

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5]>
<link href="ie5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

(via http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments)

For targeting all the IE's and fixing their issues. Wouldn't the first method be cleaner in your CSS, and simplify it? Or does it make sense to have separate CSS files for IE?

I'd love to see some links to other references/articles defending one method over the other. I see most people using the latter.

---

**Update - Check out this technique from Paul Irish!:**

This could be even better. How about this way? That way with Modernizer you could have your one stylesheet have specific section for IEs within it -

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Thoughts on that?

Comment: Why support IE 5.0?  Or 5.5 or even 6.0?  Outside of China, market share for IE 6 is typically less than 2%.  5.5 and 5.0 don't even register.  That's a lot of extra work to support a very few people.  Are they even your target demographic?

Comment: @gilly3 In my organization (3000+), we have to support internal customers/coworkers, and that means 90% of that is IE8, the current desktop supported standard at my org. Also remote workers often have IE. Ugh. It sucks I know, but in my case, here, this is something I have to consider. While we do have public sites, even those stats tell us IE is dominate (currently for our public corporate website). See breakdown - http://cl.ly/1p3F3Y093J3u3L0z1a0h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method two also reduces unnecessary traffic. Internet browsers don't share their caches so IE7 downloading IE6 his styleinfo would be useless. 
Regarding your comment about 'clean CSS', large applications are often easier to maintain when stylesheets are split per 'subject' like UI, dialogs, IE etc. Also, downloading multiple medium-sized files is faster than a large size file because of pipelining which is present in all modern browsers.

Comment: Although I don't know how often the majority of developers would run into the use case of having to scale for large websites, I do like the fact that you mentioned these factors, and explained it, hence I'm marking your answer as 'the one'. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer method 2. Any style information in the body seems less maintainable to me because you have to search for it anytime you want to make changes and also has to be changed on a page by page basis.

Comment: I second that. It's easier to maintain changes in one sheet.+1